# How define type of ref method in Quasar Framework with Vue3 and Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-composition-api, quasar-framework

- Quasar Framework v2 Beta
- Vue 3 Composition Api
- Typescript

**component template**

```
<q-btn 
  @click.stop="showingActionMenu()" 
  color="grey-7" 
  round 
  flat 
  icon="more_vert"
>
  <q-menu
    ref="showAction"
    auto-close
  >
    ...                       
  </q-menu>
</q-btn>
```

```
setup() {
  ...
  const showAction = ref<Function | null>(null)
  ...
})
```

**component setup**

```
return {
  ...
  showAction,
  showingActionMenu() {
    showAction?.value?.show()
  },
  ...
}
```

returned method shows **error**

```
Property 'show' does not exist on type 'Function'.
```

Answer (score 4):

The type of the ref should be `QMenu` which is imported from quasar framework :

```
import { QMenu } from 'quasar'
...
setup() {
  ...
  const showAction = ref<QMenu>()
  ...
  return {
    ...
    showAction,
    showingActionMenu() {
      showAction.value?.show()
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-sky-qsf6d?file=/src/pages/Index.vue:1249-1277)